# The model sent to view cannot be read in ajax get

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-mvc, model, thymeleaf

Can someone please help with this question:

I have a function that should return two different entities one as return value and the as a model. the return can be read but the model cannot.

```
$('.thumbnail').click(function(event){
  var id=($(this).data("targetelement"));
  var url='getphotos/'+id;
  $.get(url,function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
      /*<![CDATA[*/
          var product = /*[[${message}]]*/
      /*]]>*/
          console.log(product);

  });
```

});

this controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "getphotos/{id}")
public @ResponseBody ArrayList<Gallery> getPhotos(@PathVariable int id, Model model, HttpServletRequest req) {
    Product pro=service.getProduct(id);
    model.addAttribute("pro", pro);
    return service.getphotos(id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not access the model.
What you can do, is to put the model attribute into mapping that is responsible for view, process it with thymeleaf and get the photos with ajax and process them.
Or you can put both objects into something like map and return map. Then you process both objects with ajax and javascript.

Comment: Thank you, i do get the first part but i do get second part  (i.e Or you can put both objects into something like map and return map. Then you process both objects with ajax and javascript.)

Comment: If you do something like that:    

 `@GetMapping(value = "/getphotos/{id}")
    @ResponseBody
    public Map<String, Object> getPhotos(@PathVariable int id) {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("pro",12);
        map.put("photos","photos");

        return map;
    }`
 
Then you get following json response:

 `{
  "pro": 12,
  "photos": "photos"
}`